# error to set onclick event on button

Tags: android, android-layout

i have create some xml layout and i java files, some xml file have same id of the button and i create onClick event on this,
when i click this button it's generate an error shown below

```
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434): java.lang.StackOverflowError
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:313)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getString(Settings.java:494)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.provider.Settings$System.getString(Settings.java:575)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.provider.Settings$System.getInt(Settings.java:624)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.media.AudioManager.querySoundEffectsEnabled(AudioManager.java:1089)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.media.AudioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.java:1042)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.ViewRoot.playSoundEffect(ViewRoot.java:2478)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.playSoundEffect(View.java:8309)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2363)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at com.widgets.CheckBoxClass.onClick(CheckBoxClass.java:44)
08-17 01:08:12.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22434):     at android.view.View.performClick(V
```

Comment: How could be help you if you don't provide any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have got answer :

i have used that code :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.xCBApple){      
            Toast.makeText(CheckBoxClass.this,"Apple is Chedked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    if(jBackButton.performClick())
    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CheckBoxClass.this,AndroidWidgetsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

but i have to use v.getId() == R.id.backButton instead of jBackButton.performClick() and error is gone but i dont understnd about performClick() , can any one know about it ?

Thank
Rahul